# Are Bitcoin signatures currency specific?

Tags: transactions, altcoin, signature

I am wondering whether signatures for Bitcoin-like currencies are currency specific, or given one program that can sign a Bitcoin raw/JSON transaction one can create valid signatures for other coins as well?

That is to say, if a program takes:

- A private key
- A pre-contructed raw / JSON transaction

Is the signing process requiring something specific to a given currency, like referencing an address in a different form or using some currency-specific bytes?

Answer (score 1):

All coins use ECDSA to sign transactions in a similar manner, the main difference between most coins is what would constitute a valid signature, typically the first character(s) of a public address (e.g. bitcoin starts with 1 or 3 and litecoin starts with L). Therefore a certain public key could not be used directly to sign a transaction of another coin, with exception to coins such as devcoin, which uses the same address type.

You could write a program which starting from a certain private key, auto-increments until a valid address is found.

Comment: Also, you can check out vanitygen https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Vanitygen for more info on generating addresses for specific coins :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it refs the public key and also a hash of the sig content, of which the sig hash is only partially included in the txn number